# solr replication without commit in master

Tags: solr

Solr replicates from master to slave on either commit,optimize or startup.However i m setting up an empty core which acts as a slave core and I want it to replicate data from the master core without firing a commit operation on master core.

Comment: what is exactly your question? are you getting  some specific issue on your approach?

Comment: no there is no error. It is just that the slave doesnt start replicating unless I fire a commit on master and since I want only one time replication in a day I dont actually want to fire a commit on the master

Answer (score 1):

You can Force Replication on the slave from the Solr Admin dashboard.
You can also fire [replication](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Index+Replication) through url fetchindex
`http://slave_host:port/solr/replication?command=fetchindex`

> Forces the specified slave to fetch a copy of the index from its
>   master.
>
> If you like, you can pass an extra attribute such as masterUrl or
>   compression (or any other parameter which is specified in the  tag) to do a one time replication from a master. This
>   obviates the need for hard-coding the master in the slave.

Comment: I already tried this but this url only puts a replication request to the master.Unless u fire a commit on the master the replication process doesnt actually start